# "The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference."

Tags: javascript, xml, pdf, special-characters, netsuite

I am trying to create a pdf through a custom suitelet I made in netusite. I am using the API  "nlapiXMLToPDF" to create the pdf.  When I try and get values from Netsuite (using javascript) that contain an ampersand (&), and try creating the pdf, I get the error

> The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference.

```
strName += "<div class=\"" + divs[divVal] + "\">";
strName += "<table class = \"gentable\" style=\"width: 25%; margin-top:20px;margin-bottom: 20px;\"><tr><td class=\"addressheader\">Shipping Address</td></tr>";
strName += "<tr>"; 
strName += "<td class=\"address\">"  + Address + "</td>";
strName += "</tr>";
strName += "<tr>";
strName += "<td class=\"addressheader\">Phone</td>";
strName += "</tr>";
strName += "<tr>";
strName += "<td>" + Phone + "</td>";
strName += "</tr></table>";
```

Address and Phone are pulling values from netsuite fields. Some of these fields contain an "&". When I try and replace the "&" with

```
&amp;
```

using something like

```
Address.replace("&", "&amp;");
```

I do not get the error anymore and the pdf generates fine, except now it shows the "& amp;" on the pdf form. If I don't use the replace method, I get the error.

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

**FIXED**

Enclosing my values with the netsuite API nlapiEscapeXML() fixed my issues. I don't know how I seem to have overlooked that.

Comment: `&` is a special character; replacing it with the entity version fixes the parsing. You already fixed this, why did you post the question?

Comment: The & amp; appears on the pdf document. While the problem is fixed in terms of not showing an error message anymore, I cannot have documents that say "Barnes & amp; Noble" for ex.

Answer (score 0):

Try escaping the Address alone and not the whole XML string. when you replaced the "&" in the Address it is already correct `"Barnes &amp; Noble"` so when you generate it it will display as "Barnes & Noble".

But what you did is replace the "&" in the address having it as `"Barnes &amp; Noble"` then you use nlapiEscapeXML that will give you `"Barnes &amp; amp; Noble"` which is the reason why you are getting `"Barnes & amp; Noble"`